# Why is my Model Serializer's validated_data is different from form input?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using Django 1.8, DRF and AngularJS. I have a form on the frontend:

```
<form ng-submit="ctrl.add()">
    <label>Username</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.user.username">

    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password" ng-model="ctrl.user.password">

    <label>Country</label>
        <select ng-model="ctrl.user.country">
            <option value="">Select your country.</option>
            <option value="USA">USA</option>
            <option value="Canada">CA</option>
        </select>

    <input type="submit" value="Register">
</form>
```

Assume a user registers. This form sends `user.username`, `user.password` and `user.country` to the backend. This is my UserSerializer:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    country = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='countryName', source='userextended.country', queryset=Country.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password', 'country')
        read_only_field = ('country')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create_user(
            username = validated_data['username'],
            password = validated_data['password'],
        )
        UserExtended.objects.create(user=user, country=validated_data['userextended']['country'])
        return user
```

This was code I wrote a while back and it seems to work. My question is regarding this line:

```
UserExtended.objects.create(user=user, country=validated_data['userextended']['country'])
```

Why is it not:

```
UserExtended.objects.create(user=user, country=validated_data['country'])
```

because the object which JS passes to the backend is user.username, user.password and user.country, not user.userexnteded.country.

Where did the `'userextended'` come from?

Comment: Apparently it comes from your `UserExtended` model: `source='userextended.country'`. It's needed to avoid collisions i.e. imagine if both models had a field called `name`.

Comment: @François That's what I'm guessing, but where is the documentation which states that `source` changes the format of `validated_data` (i.e. changes from `user.country` to `user.userextended.country`?